# Having issue with a complicated regex python

Tags: regex, search

---

```
 s = {"densityThreshold": 2.4543288981124E+14}
```

I was thinking something like this

```
 re.search(".[A-Za-z]*.:\s\d\.\d+..\d+", k) or if re.search(".[A-Za-z]*.:\s\d\.\w+.\d+", k):
```

but neither seem to work..

I need to group "densityThreshold" and "2.4543288981124E+14" to create another dictionary.. I would usually use group() but i m stuck at search!

Comment: Have you considered using `eval()` instead?

Comment: I prefer to correct where I am going wrong in the above..

Comment: Sure, but there's a case to be made that this is a [classical abuse of regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) (<- linked).

Comment: For the record, however, your example works perfectly fine when I try it. What's the actual problem?

Comment: both the  "re.search()" or just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
x='s = {"densityThreshold": 2.4543288981124E+14}'
k=re.search(".[A-Za-z]*.:\s\d\.\d+..\d+", x)
print k.group()
```

You can do this if you want the whole thing in one group.Or if you want separately use

```
x='s = {"densityThreshold": 2.4543288981124E+14
k=re.search("(.[A-Za-z]*.):(\s\d\.\d+..\d+)", x)
print k.groups()
```